# karma and jasmine configuration for typescript in angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple application components in angular 6. I configure my webpack for dev and prod built and both are working fine. I am trying to configure a unit test env using karma, jasmine for my app and was not successful since yesterday. I just need to execute unit test with cocverage no e2e. Install my karma and jasmine. I then went through the karma init which generated the file below.

// Karma configuration

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'src/index.ts',
      'src/**/**.spec.ts'
    ],
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome']
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

I then added a simple .spec.ts test in a component called mycomponent.spec.ts

```
describe('example test', function () {
    it('should be true', function () {
        expect('foo').toBe('foo');
    });
});
```

When i run my test , i get the error below.

> Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR   {
>       "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export",
>       "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"   } Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0):
>   Executed 1 of 1 ERROR (0.013 secs / 0.001 secs)

I have been trying to fix this and set up  my environment since yesterday. I came across a suggestion for using karma-typescript. However, i get a lot of webpack error when i use it. Please how do i set this up ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code in my project and modified it with below code.

Please try below code, if it doesn't work then let me know

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine','@angular/cli' ],
        plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-sourcemap-loader'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter')
    ],


    files: [
      'src/index.ts',
      'src/**/**.spec.ts'
    ],
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    client: {
            codeCoverage: config.angularCli.codeCoverage,
            clearContext: false
          },


    angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev',
            apps: config.angularCli.codeCoverage ? '1' : '0'
          },

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },


    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,

  })
}
```